# Can't check Bootstrap checkbox inside modal

Tags: html, bootstrap-modal

I have an issue when trying to check a checkbox inside a form inside a modal.

Here the code

```
    <div id="modal-new-bill" class="modal">
        <form action="NewBill" method="post">  
            <div class="modal-content">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" value="remender" name="remender">
                        <label for="remender">Create Remender?</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer center">

                <a href="#!" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-red btn-flat">Cancel</a>
                <button type="submit" class="btn waves-effect waves-light">Insert</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

The problem is that i can't check that checkbox but if i came to it by tab clicks and then space it, it gets checked. anyone know how to made it checked by mouse click?.
Thanks.

Comment: The HTML you've posted seems to be deviating a bit from the correct Bootstrap markup structure. Make sure you are checking for that. You can use http://www.bootlint.com/ and it'll report all the problems with your markup. For example, you don't have a `.modal-dialog` and you have a `.row` without any column children

Answer (score 0):

It is working as you posted so you most likely have some JavaScript attached to it causing your issue.

```html
<div id="modal-new-bill" class="modal">
        <form action="NewBill" method="post">  
            <div class="modal-content">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" value="remender" name="remender">
                        <label for="remender">Create Remender?</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer center">

                <a href="#!" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-red btn-flat">Cancel</a>
                <button type="submit" class="btn waves-effect waves-light">Insert</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```